# Adding a pilot light to a light switch

Tags: lighting

I want to add a pilot light to a light in my basement. I want to position the pilot light upstairs so when I'm upstairs I will know if the light has been left on in the basement. I'd like a recommendation on the simplest way to complete this.

Comment: I suppose the light in the basement is controlled by a single switch which is in the basement, right? That is, it is not controlled by two switches, one of which is upstairs, right?

Comment: You could purchase a standard 120v indicator light, connect some romex at the switch or light whichever is easiest run the romex upstairs where you want the indicator, mount an old work box, drill a hole for the light in a blank cover connect the conductors and fasten the plate to the box, now every time the light is turned on the light will be iluminated.

Comment: @EdBeal -- that sounds like an answer to me

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your setup you may find it more convenient to do as Ed Beal suggests but instead of installing a pilot light put in a **3-way switch with pilot light**. This way when you find out the basement light is on you don't have to walk downstairs to turn it off.

Remember that you will need enough conductors in the cable for the hot, neutral, travelers, and ground. And that you will have to swap out the switch downstairs for a three-way (no pilot).

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you want at all, but...

I had a similar problem with my garage.  Well, two problems.  First, the light would get left on, and second, the garage door would get left open.

For the light, I ended up getting a switch with a timer so that even if I left the light on, it would turn of on its own.  They also make light bulbs that have an integrated timing circuit so there is no switch to wire.

For the garage door problem, I installed a peep hole in the door going to the garage.  Without even holding my eye all the way up to it I can immediately see if there is a super bright light from the door being open or if it's dark from the door being closed.

Either of these solutions could work for you, but it's not the pilot light you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You could purchase a standard 120v indicator light, connect some romex at the switch or light whichever is easiest run the romex upstairs where you want the indicator, mount an old work box, drill a hole for the light in a blank cover connect the conductors and fasten the plate to the box, now every time the light is turned on the light will be iluminated. This would be code compliant as the connections are made in boxes, I have some 120v 1/3watt wamco. Lamps wl-1050c1 that I use for equipment these neon lamps last forever and are UL listed for under $2.00 USD (just an example not an endorsement of this brand.